# Django loading templatetags from nested apps doesn't working correctly

Tags: django, django-templates, django-custom-tags

File structure:

```
_project_
   __init__.py
   settings/ 
       __init__.py
       settings.py
   apps/
       __init__.py
       newapp/
           __init__.py
           models.py
           ....
           templatetags/
               __init__.py
               test_tag.py

...
__init__.py
manage.py
```

test_tag.py contains:

```
from django import template
from django.template.defaultfilters import stringfilter

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
@stringfilter
def lower(value):
    return value.lower()
```

test.html contains:

```
{% load test_tag from _project_.apps.newapp.templatetags %}
```

Django 1.5 Shell ( python manage.py shell ):

```
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from _project_.apps.newapp.templatetags import test_tag
>>> test_tag.lower("QWERTY")
u'qwerty'
```

Django's 1.5 settings:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    '_project_.apps.newapp',
    ...
)

TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
)
```

But Django 1.5 generates exception TemplateSyntaxError:

```
'_project_.apps.newapp.templatetags' is not a valid tag library: Template library _project_.apps.newapp.templatetags not found, tried ...
```

P.S: Server restarted, *.pyc files removed, but problem exists. When 'newapp' located in /*project*/newapp/ - all OK.

Comment: And the question is... "how do I fix it?"?

Comment: >> And the question is... "how do I fix it?"?
Yes, because I wrote question with problem and without 'answer'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you must be fix load templat tag in your html page

```
{% load test_tag %}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's works for me! In this situation [KISS Principle won](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) :)

Answer (score 1):

You're using the `{% load %}` syntax in a wrong way. Accoring to [the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/builtins/#load) the `{% load foo from bar %}` loads tag or filter named `foo` from tag library called `bar`. In your case `{% load test_tag from _project_.apps.newapp.templatetags %}` the `test_tag` is a name of the library instead of a tag or filter name.

So it should be more like:

```
{% load lower from test_tag  %}
```